# Test status update in robot framework from listener based on keyword status

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I have designed the test suite where I am calling listeners to run the keyword-based on the keyword failure log and status.

Robot code

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library     RunOnFailureLibrary.py
Test Template   Run Keyword And Ignore Error
Suite Setup    Set Keyword To Run On Failure    Test Keyword    key     first  

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    log     test
    fail  something went wrong
    log     test1

Test 2
    pass execution  test

Test 3

    log     test
    fail    something 
    log     test1


*** Keywords ***
Test Keyword
    [Arguments]     ${arg1}     ${arg2}     ${arg3}
    log     ${arg1}
    log     ${arg2}
    log     ${arg3}
```

Listener code:  RunOnFailureLibrary.py

```
from robot.api import logger
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


class RunOnFailureLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 0.1

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure = None
        self.keyword_args = None
        self.log_Error= None

    def set_keyword_to_run_on_failure(self, keyword, *args):
        # print("args",args)
        if len(args) > 0:
            self.keyword_args = args
        self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure = keyword

    def _log_message(self, message):
        self.log_Error=message["message"]


    def _end_keyword(self, name, attributes):
        if attributes['status'] == 'FAIL' and self.log_Error=="something went wrong":
            logger.info(f"Running keyword:'{self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure}' on failure!")
            if attributes['args'] is None:
                    logger.info("This doesnt Looks like healing")
                    return False
            else:
                print(*self.keyword_args)
                BuiltIn().run_keyword(self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure,self.keyword_args[0],attributes["args"][0],
                                      self.keyword_args[1])

globals()[__name__] = RunOnFailureLibrary
```

As you see from the robot code, I am calling the `Test Keyword` based on the `status` of the keyword if it is `fail` and the log error is `something went wrong`. If this condition is not satisfied we will NOT be running this keyword.

The problem is as I have used in the Test Template `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` to make sure all the keywords run in the test case, so irrespective of status is it will be marked as a pass which is understandable .

But I want to achieve something like , if the listener keyword  `Test Keyword` is called, I want to update the status of the test case to be based on the success or failure of this keyword. So Test Case 1 Result status must be based on the `Test Keyword`.

In Test case 3, the listener will not call the keyword as the error message is NOT matching the condition, So the test case must fail. But it will be shown as a pass due to `Test Template`

Is there any way , we can handle this

Comment: @Todor Minakov , previously  helped any idea on this

Comment: @Bence Kaulics , previously you have helped any idea on this